# ¿Para que se usa try .. finally sin la clausula catch?

Tags: java, groovy

Hago mantenimiento de un sistema heredado, y he visto en muchas partes un bloque similar a lo que sigue:

```
try {
  // aqui codigo

} finally {
  // mas codigo aqui
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cual es la función de hacer un `try .. finally`, sin el bloque `catch`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Los **contratos** son un concepto común en el diseño y análisis de la corrección de los algoritmos.  El concepto es que las funciones, métodos u otras unidades de nuestros programas deben tener:

- **Precondiciones:** Condiciones que los llamantes deben proveer de antemano para que el método produzca resultados correctos;
- **Postcondiciones:** Condiciones que (dadas las precondiciones) el método promete se darán cuando regrese;
- **Invariantes:** Condiciones que el método promete que no afectará—serán ciertas o falsas al regresar si y sólo si lo eran al entrar.

En este marco, el `try { ... } finally { ... }` es un constructo útil para que nuestro código pueda garantizar [postcondiciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondici%C3%B3n) aún cuando se den excepciones dentro del bloque del `try { ... }` o en cualquier método invocado dentro de este bloque.  Dado que los comandos dentro del bloque `finally { ... }` siempre se van a ejecutar, excepción o no, es común poner ahí código que garantiza las postcondiciones.

Los ejemplos de "limpieza" que otros han dado caen dentro de este marco.  La idea es que en estos ejemplos:

1. Se usa un recurso tal como un archivo o una conexión a una base de datos;
2. Existe una postcondición que obliga al código del ejemplo a garantizar que el recurso se cerrará no importa lo que pase en su uso.

Este era el uso más común del `finally` en versiones viejas de Java.  En Java 7 se introdujo un nuevo constructo, llamado "try with resources," que suplanta el `try { ... } finally { ... }` en sus usos más comunes:

```
try (OutputStream out = ...) {
    // usar el OutputStream `out`
} // postcondición: `out` ha sido cerrado
```

Otra clase de ejemplo es con las herramientas de sincronización entre hilos ("threads").  En el paquete [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) existen varias clases de cerraduras ("locks") que normalmente se usan con `try {...} finally {...}`:

```
Lock l = ...;
l.lock();
try {
    // Entre los hilos que comparten la cerradura `l`, sólo uno
    // puede entrar en este bloque a la vez.
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}  // postcondición: la cerradura está abierta
```

Pero cabe recalcar de nuevo el concepto de las postcondiciones.  Al fin y al cabo, el `try { ... } finally { ... }` no es específicamente un mecanismo de "limpieza" sino una herramienta general para facilitar la composición de programas correctos.  Así que tiene otros usos, aún si son mucho menos comunes que estos dos.

---

Cabe añadir otro tipo de ejemplos.  Una causa frecuente de errores de programación es la salida temprana ("early return") de una función o método.  Los casos típicos son algo así:

```
public LoQueSea miMétodo(Desto algo, Coso queSéYo) {
    // muchas lineas...

    if (noSéQué()) {
        return new LoQueSea(algo);  // salida temprana
    } 

    // muchas más lineas...

    cosaQueSiempreTieneQuePasar(queSéYo);
    return new LoQueSea(algo.con(queSéYo));
}
```

Suponiendo que siempre nos es necesario llamar el método `cosaQueSiempreTieneQuePasar()`, este ejemplo tiene un error: cuando `noSéQué()` regresa con `true` salimos temprano y nos olvidamos de llamar `cosaQueSiempreTieneQuePasar()`.  Una solución en muchos casos es lo siguiente:

```
public LoQueSea miMétodo(Desto algo, Coso queSéYo) {
    try {
        // muchas lineas...

        if (noSéQué()) {
            return new LoQueSea(algo);  // salida temprana
        } 

        // muchas más lineas...
        return new LoQueSea(algo.con(queSéYo));
    } finally {
        // Este bloque se ejecuta siempre, aun si hay 
        // salida temprana.
        cosaQueSiempreTieneQuePasar(queSéYo);
    }
}
```

Y aquí cabe fijare que, a pesar de que muchas respuestas han mencionado las excepciones como el motivo para el `try {...} finally {...}`, este ejemplo muestra que nos podemos topar con problemas aun si no hay excepciones.  Otros ejemplos son posibles con `break` y `continue` en las estructuras de repetición como `for (...) {...}`.

O más bien, las excepciones, el `return` temprano, el `break` y el `continue` tienen algo en común—salida temprana de un bloque de código—y el `finally` es una solución común para los problemas que causan todos estos.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer no es una tan mala práctica ya que el `finally`  siempre se va a ejecutar se puede utilizar para hacer limpieza. Encontré un par de ejemplos en la red:

Ejemplo 1

```
public void yourMethod() throws YourException {
    try {
        db.store(mydata);
    } finally {
        db.cleanup();
    }
}
```

Ejemplo 2

```
OutputStream os = null;
OutputStreamWriter wos = null;
try { 
   os = new FileOutputStream(...);
   wos = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
   // ......

   wos.flush();
   os.flush();
finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(wos);
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
}
```

Aqui un usuario dice que en el siguiente ejemplo el `catch` no sabría que hacer con el error por lo que sería mejor agregar una rutina de limpieza.

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    // Hacer algo que lance una excepción
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
         try {
             in.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
         // Nothing we can do.
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 por incluir ejemplos con *streams*. Un estándar *de-facto* para el `finally` es la liberación de recursos por parte de la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

El bloque `catch` sirve solo para atrapar alguna excepción que aparezca durante la ejecución del código. Puesto que no hay bloque `catch`, la excepción saltará y será manejada por el cliente del método donde se encuentre este bloque de código. Si no hay ningún manejo de esta excepción, entonces la excepción saltará hasta el nivel más alto que pueda alcanzar. Si el nivel más alto es el método `public static void main(String[] args)` de la aplicación y allí no se maneja, entonces la aplicación mostrará la excepción que se ha lanzado y "terminará".

Cabe resaltar que el bloque `finally` siempre se ejecuta, sea que la excepción se haya lanzado hasta el nivel más alto de la aplicación. Hay casos donde no se ejecuta `finally` pero son externos a esta respuesta. Puedes verlos [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035/1065197)

Utiliza `try-finally` cuando tu código no necesita manejar la excepción porque ya existe otro nivel donde se manejará. Por ejemplo, en una aplicación web donde tienes algún componente X que decora a los componentes que ejecutan las peticiones y X ya tiene una forma de trabajar las excepciones por defecto, que automáticamente las va a logear y mostrará un mensaje "bonito" al usuario (no sé cuál mensaje de error es bonito en realidad). Un ejemplo de este ejemplo (valga la redundancia) es el caso de Spring MVC donde puedes utilizar `@ControllerAdvice` para manejar las excepciones a nivel general. De esta manera, si tu código lanza una excepción no la manejará él sino la clase decorada con esta anotación.

No es una mala práctica, es un tema de orden.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya mencionaron otras personas, `try` con `finally` sirve para hacer limpieza en caso que ocurra una excepción, *sin* cachar esa excepción.

A partir de Java 7 que tienes *try with resources*, ya pueden existir incluso bloques que únicamente incluyen `try`:

```
try (OutputStream s = getOutputStream()) {
    //usar s
}
```

El `finally` sobra porque el stream se va a cerrar terminando el bloque.

Answer (score 0):

Se podría utilizar en procesos que si fallan, no hace falta ser informados, ni alertar al usuario. pero es una mala practica, mínimo debería grabar un log de excepciones en el catch

Comment: Si salta una excepción, esta detendrá la ejecución del stack y si no se captura en ningún lado pues la excepción se mostrará al usuario de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

La clausula completa es: Try, Catch and Finally. Es posible que no hayan utilizado el bloque de captura del error pues no era necesario realizar algún tipo de notificación... Sin embargo, deberías agregarlo para, en un futuro, identificar mejor el por qué y el dónde está ocurriendo el problema.

Answer (score 0):

- Para cerrar recursos (p.e. ficheros abiertos) sin interrumpir el flujo de lanzamiento de excepciones cuando se produce alguna.
- Para poner en ese bloque un codigo que siempre queremos que se ejecute, independiente de si se lanzan excepciones o no, p.e.: `System.out.println("Salgo de la funcion Clase1.pepito()");`