# ¿Qué sentido tiene usar una sentencia try-catch-finally sin un catch? (ver código)

Tags: java, excepciones, try-catch

[image: Código sin catch]
Pues nada eso, que estoy en primero y no tengo ni idea d programar

Comment: puedes que esto resuelva tu duda(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4112/para-que-se-usa-try-finally-sin-la-clausula-catch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ausencia del catch también tiene su importancia.

Se puede utilizar esta estructura try/finally cuando no queremos manejar los errores (se permite que se pierdan), pero queremos asegurarnos de que los procesos que comenzamos estén finalizados, se haya procesado el try correctamente o no (la excepción generada se devolverá a quien hizo esta llamada, y de este al anterior, y así hasta el nivel más alto que pueda alcanzar si no es tratada antes -por ejemplo, llegando al método main()-, lanzando en última instancia una excepción que finalizaría el programa).

Hay varias respuestas más completas aquí:
[[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4112/para-que-se-usa-try-finally-sin-la-clausula-catch]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4112/para-que-se-usa-try-finally-sin-la-clausula-catch)

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.